# Split list into sublists by delimiter

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop

I have a list of lists:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

I want to split it into what comes before the list [0,1,0] and what comes after like so:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0]]
```

If I had a list:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

I would want to split it into a list like this:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]
```

I am really stuck with this while loop, which does not seem to reset the temporary list at the right place:

```
def count_normal_jumps(jumps):
    _temp1 = []
    normal_jumps = []
    jump_index = 0
    while jump_index <= len(jumps) - 1:
        if jumps[jump_index] == [0,0]:
            _temp1.append(jumps[jump_index])
        else:
            normal_jumps.append(_temp1)
            _temp1[:] = []
        jump_index += 1
    return normal_jumps
```

Why does this not work and is there a better approach?

Comment: Can there be sublists like `[0, 1, 0, 1]` and if yes what happens then?

Comment: No. It is always assumed the list starts and ends with 0. I might expand the problem if I get time, but that's just a case of evaluating edge cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to append the sublists in the list to the last sublist in a list of lists, and append a new sublist to the list of lists when the input sublist is equal to `[0, 1, 0]`:

```
def split(lst):
    output = [[]]
    for l in lst:
        if l == [0, 1, 0]:
            output.append([])
        else:
            output[-1].append(l)
    return output
```

or you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
def split(lst):
    return [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst, key=[0, 1, 0].__ne__) if k]
```

so that:

```
print(split([[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0]]))
print(split([[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0]]))
```

outputs:

```
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0]]]
[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0]], [[0, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
myList = [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0]]

toMatch = [0, 1, 0]
allMatches = []

currentMatches = []
for lst in myList:
    if lst == toMatch:
        allMatches.append(currentMatches)
        currentMatches = []
    else:
        currentMatches.append(lst)

#push leftovers when end is reached
if currentMatches:
    allMatches.append(currentMatches)

print(allMatches)
```